# Getting requests on which a user have answered

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have two tables. **Requests** and **Answers** with the column **RequestId** binding them together.
Now, I am able to get the answers for a specific request by doing something like, Request.Answers...

But how do I use this relationship to get only requests where the **UserId**-column in Answers equals something?

What I want to achieve is that a user can list the requests only on which he has answered.

Something like:

```
    Requests.Where(x=>x.Answers(y=>y.UserId==currentUserId))



    public class Request
    {
       [Key]
       public int RequestId { get; set;
       public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answer
    {
       [Key]
       public int AnswerId { get; set; }
       public int RequestId { get; set; }
       public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
       public int UserId { get; set; }
     }
```

I have managed to solve this by first getting all AnswersId's and group by RequestId, and then loop through the results to add requests to a list. But that seems to be a very inefficent way do to this.

Is there a easier way to get this done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will return all requests which have answers

```
Requests.Where(r => r.Answers.Any())
```

You haven't provide any `UserId` property on `Answer` entity. But if you have one, then getting all request which have answers from particular user looks like

```
Requests.Where(r => r.Answers.Any(a => a.UserId == userId))
```